# Way to back-up phone numbers on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, backup, windows, contacts

What is a good service to back up my contacts on my iPhone?

Comment: what do you have? windows, mac, other?

Comment: i have windows.

Answer (score 2):

I use Google services and probably you as well, I love the translate, the email, documents, reader (RSS), etc ...

So, why not using Google Contacts as your "middle men" and sync them with your Apple Mobile device?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

iTunes can create backups of your iOS device when you:
* Sync with iTunes (disabled if you have iCloud backup turned on)
* Right-click (or Control-click) the iOS device in iTunes under Devices and choose Back Up

Use these steps to manually back up your iOS device using iTunes:

1. Connect your iOS device to a computer with the latest version of iTunes installed
2. Select your iOS device in iTunes under Devices
3. Right-click (or Control-click) the device and select Back Up

Resource:
How to back up and restore from a backup
http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1766

Comment: It might be worth noting that this backups the whole iPhone (not just contacts) and that you are going to need another iPhone to restore it to in case your phone gets lost/broken.

Answer (score 1):

By syncing your contacts with your computer (you also get a backup of the data on your phone each time you sync sans music, photos and the actual applications themselves - just the data). iTunes will talk to Address Book on Mac OS X and Outlook on Windows for desktop applications, otherwise you can use MobileMe, Yahoo or even Gmail as well to sync your contacts.

You can also export your contacts as vCards from your phone or address book of choice and save those somewhere.

Comment: i didn't see where iTunes stores my contacts. i found iDriveLite application that backs up contacts on their site.

Comment: iTunes doesn't store your contacts except in the backup (which isn't easily read without another program) - it acts as a conduit between your address book program of choice and your iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

If you've got a GMail account you can use the google exchange support to sync your contacts (and calendars). This uses push updates so you don't need to connect to iTunes to back up your contacts. Full details [here](http://www.google.com/support/mobile/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=138740)